# Откуда появилось окончание [а] в древнерусском языке?

Tags: окончания, источники

Откуда появилось окончание [а] в древнерусском, что оно означало?

Comment: @Аннаааа, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем по теме, но вспомнилось, что **в латыни** (в ед. числе, именит. падеже) окончание -а обычно означает **женский род**.

Мужской -us, средний -um.

Например:

optimus - лучший
optima - лучшая
optimum - лучшее

.

Ещё у некоторых латин. слов окончание -а может появляться **во множественном числе**. Другое распространённое окончание мн. числа -i.

.

**Конкретно по Вашему вопросу.**
Могу предположить, что в русском языке окончание -а имеет очень древнее происхождение. Возможно, праиндоевропейское.

Во всяком случае могу определённо сказать, что к примеру окончание мн. числа -i считается праиндоевропейским. Что сохранилось и в современном русском языке, как -и или (более твёрдо) -ы.

Воробей - воробьи, голубь - голуби, рука - руки.

Это я к тому, что если окончание -и смогло сохраниться в нашем языке и прийти из такой глубокой древности, то можно предположить подобное и для окончания -а.

Comment: это от того, что женщины всегда кричат  ааааа,  то ли от испуга, то ли от боли.
Мужики всегда восхищаются,  ооо. а от боли мычат.А еще на Я и Ё, говорят умные слова. это в России.

Answer (score 0):

Флексия какой части речи? По-моему, Вам нужно обратиться к учебникам исторической грамматики.

http://mling.ru/iazik/russe/gramm_hist/

http://www.booksshare.net/index.php?id1=4&category=lunguistics&author=gorshkova- kv&book=1981&page=76

Очень распространена в древнерусских текстах типично церковнославянская флексия -а (орфографически -а или -ы — восточнославянская передача старославянской флексии -га) в соответствии с -гь II класса (следовательно, в P ед. ч. и в И-В мн. ч.): отъ земл-я, единъ отъ брати-я, мъногы суди-я, умыкиваху дгъвиц-я. Некоторые окончания, встречающиеся изредка уже в старейших текстах, отражают процесс перегруппировки исходной для древнерусского языка системы склонения существительных, а потому не должны учитываться при реконструкции этой исходной системы, если нет оснований считать их диалектными праславянскими.

http://gigabaza.ru/doc/786-pall.html

На этом сайте нет преподавателей высшей школы, смотрите лекции и учебники

Answer (score 0):

"Флексия какой части речи?" (Людмила).

Одна из древнейших частей - числительные. Практически самое древнее количественное числительное - два, далее - оба, пара, а после и двойка, тройка и т.д.

Что означало -а? Само по себе - ничего, а в словах - признак двойственности и парности частей тела, кратную множественность.